# Why doesn't Motorola Moto G4 sometimes not accept phone calls?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, lineageos, motorola

I'm using a Motorola Moto G4 Play with LineageOS. From time to time I get a message that someone tried to call me, but I wasn't available. This hasn't happened with other phones, so I suspect that it is some bug/bad behaviour.

From what I can tell this usually happens when the phone is locked. However at least once it happened when I was using the phone. The phone itself is not in "Do not disturb" mode. But I try to disable it (although it is disabled) my impression is that phone calls come through. As far as I can tell the phone always has radio reception. So I'm out of ideas what can cause this behaviour.

How can I debug this behaviour or do know what can cause this behaviour?

Comment: You have a custom ROM, so one possibility is that the modem (radio ) is not optimised for your region?? If that is the case, flashing modem that suits your region may help

Comment: Jens, are you by any chance in Germany, and your provider is O2? And your device is LTE/4G capable, plus at the time of the calls you were on 4G data? If so, it might not be an issue with your device or OS. Unless your device is VoLTE capable, you cannot receive calls while in LTE – so the provider usually sends "a code" to the device to drop to 3G/2G in order to receive the incoming call. O2 had some issues with that lately and didn't send that "code". Quite a feeling when all those "missed call" SMSs drop in at once when you suddenly drop to 3G/2G a while later, I can tell ;)

Comment: @beeshyams Custom ROMs, at least for Moto devices, don't include modems, the modem in the device should be whatever was in the device last time it was stock. That said, troubleshooting issues like this is difficult, I would recommend trying Safe Mode and/or  returning to stock and see if the issue recurs to verify if it's a really a issue with LineageOS or not.

Comment: @acejavelin - Thanks, haven't switched to custom ROM on Moto X Play, so didn't know about that.// Your approach makes sense but gut feeling is what izzy said is more likely - OP profile says Germany

Comment: @beeshyams Could be... This could also be a carrier issue, I struggle with this in some areas on AT&T in the US, people will message me they tried to call and my phone didn't ring, happens quite frequently in south St Paul and Eagan, Minnesota, but never once in North Dakota anywhere. I have changed SIMs/phones/ROMs/modems and more, still an issue in some areas of the country so I know the frustration this user feels.

Comment: @Izzy your guess is correct. I am on O2, but not sure if 4G or not.

Comment: @Izzy: JFTR: If I downgrade to use 3G/2G, is it more likely that phone calls will reach me? Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @JensKubieziel You understood correctly. Worth a try to lock it to 3G (should be sufficient and, concerning the issue, not different from 2G) just to see if the issue persists. I have 2 phones (businness/private), one of them LTE capable the other not. Cannot remember having had this issue with the non-LTE device (3G/2G), but quite often with the LTE one. Both devices were forced to O2 (I was with E+ for 20+ years until the "merger" eliminated that company).